# Determine Which Duplicate Images to Remove using Python Dictionary

Tags: python

I've written a script that identifies duplicate and near-duplicate images based on some criteria. The results are placed in a dictionary where the keys represent an image and the values are duplicate images. For example, for image0 there are duplicate images 1-5. Now, I'm trying to make a list of candidates to delete based on my dictionary. I'd like to keep the first image that appears in the dictionary (image0), delete images 1-5, and then skip keys 1-5 because those images have already been removed. How would I do this? Or is there a better way to go about identifying candidates for deletion?

Example Dictionary:

```
{0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 1: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 2: [0, 1, 3, 4, 5],
 3: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5],
 4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 5],
 5: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 6: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
 7: [6, 8, 9, 10, 11],
 8: [6, 7, 9, 10, 11],
 9: [6, 7, 8, 10, 11],
 10: [6, 7, 8, 9, 11],
 11: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
 12: [13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
 13: [12, 14, 15, 16, 17],
 14: [12, 13, 15, 16, 17],
 15: [12, 13, 14, 16, 17],
 16: [12, 13, 14, 15, 17],
 17: [12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
 18: [19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
 19: [18, 20, 21, 22, 23],
 20: [18, 19, 21, 22, 23],
 21: [18, 19, 20, 22, 23],
 22: [18, 19, 20, 21, 23],
 23: [18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
 24: [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
 25: [24, 26, 27, 28, 29],
 26: [24, 25, 27, 28, 29],
 27: [24, 25, 26, 28, 29],
 28: [24, 25, 26, 27, 29],
 29: [24, 25, 26, 27, 28],
 30: [31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
 31: [30, 32, 33, 34, 35],
 32: [30, 31, 33, 34, 35],
 33: [30, 31, 32, 34, 35],
 34: [30, 31, 32, 33, 35],
 35: [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
 36: [37, 38, 39],
 37: [36, 38, 39],
 38: [36, 37, 39],
 39: [36, 37, 38],
 40: [41, 42, 43],
 41: [40, 42, 43],
 42: [40, 41, 43],
 43: [40, 41, 42],
 44: [45, 46],
 45: [44, 46],
 46: [44, 45]}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you think the problem is. Have you tried doing it?

Comment: As your question is not very clear please include the desired output for the provided example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a set 'removed'  with removed indexes inside.

So when you loop your dict , add the indexes in the removed set

and  every time you don't know if a particular index was removed you can search it into your set .  if the set contains the index the image with this index  was removed by you.

for example:

```
s = set()
d = {0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 1: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 2: [0, 1, 3, 4, 5],
 3: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5],
 4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 5],
 5: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 6: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
 7: [6, 8, 9, 10, 11],
 8: [6, 7, 9, 10, 11],
 9: [6, 7, 8, 10, 11],
 10: [6, 7, 8, 9, 11]
 ... more ...
}

def delete_image(idx):
    '...your delete stuff...'

for k in d:
    for idx in d[k]:
        if not idx in s:
            delete_image(idx)
            s.add(idx)
        
>>> s
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
```

So at the end s set contains all index deleted or to delete if you prefer.

Comment: This code is making the same mistake as @Synthase, but has the added benefits of being more confusing and doing more than what the OP asked for.  What is that result at the end of your answer?  Is that what you get if you only run through the first 11 entries in the input dict?

Comment: Yes, is what you get if you only run through the first 11 entries in the input dict.  The user asked: 
" I'd like to keep the first image that appears in the dictionary (image0), delete images 1-5, and then skip keys 1-5 because those images have already been removed."  .   I think my example script do exactly what the user asked for.   But Sorry for the "...more ..."  inside the dict . It means ".. the are more elements here ..."

Answer (score 2):

The logic of what you want to do is very straightforward.  You can keep a set of delete candidates.  You iterate over the keys in the dict.  For each key, you look for it in the set.  If it's there, then you don't want to process it because it has already been determined to be a key you want to delete.  If it isn't there, then the value in that key's dictionary contains a list of keys that you want to delete, and so you add all of those keys to the list of delete candidates.

If you really want a list as the result, at the end you can convert the set to a list.

Here's the code to do that:

```
dups = set()

for i in data:
    if i not in dups:
        dups = dups.union(data[i])

print(list(dups))
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 45, 46]
```

Answer (score -2):

**In case you just want the list, a oneliner is possible:**

```
list_img = list(set([item for sublist in dic.values() for item in sublist]))

print (list_img)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 6, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 18, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 24, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 30, 37, 38, 39, 36, 41, 42, 43, 40, 45, 46, 44]
```

Otherwise:

```
img = {}; list_img = []

for key, values in dic.items():
    for i, value in enumerate(values):
        if str(value) not in img.keys():
            img[str(value)] = True
        else:
            values[i] = -1

dic = {key: [value for value in dic[key] if value != -1] for key in dic.keys()}

dic = {key: values for key, values in dic.items() if values != []}

for key in dic.keys():
    print (key, dic[key])
    list_img.append(dic[key])

list_img = [item for sublist in list_img for item in sublist]

print (list_img)
```

Output:

```
0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1 [0]
6 [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
7 [6]
12 [13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
13 [12]
18 [19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
19 [18]
24 [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
25 [24]
30 [31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
31 [30]
36 [37, 38, 39]
37 [36]
40 [41, 42, 43]
41 [40]
44 [45, 46]
45 [44]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 6, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 12, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 18, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 24, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 30, 37, 38, 39, 36, 41, 42, 43, 40, 45, 46, 44]
```

Comment: This adds every image to the list rather than all but one of each set of duplicates :( - Note the `0` entry in the fifth position in the list.  It shouldn't be there.

Comment: I've seen that yes. Tbh I was not sure to understand what the OP wanted. Well, he did not accept any answer so we don t know.

Comment: I don't find that to be true.  It seems pretty clear what they want.  What part of "keep the first image that appears in the dictionary (image0), delete images 1-5" is unclear to you?

Comment: "for image0 there are duplicate images 1-5." There is a confusion between dict keys and values in list. It may be image appearing as keys, as values, or both. I based my code on values.

Comment: The fact that you're using only the values is where you are running into trouble.  The right thing to do is to use both keys and values.  Each key is an image number, and each value is a list of image numbers.  There is one dict entry for each value.  The key is an image number and the value is a list of the numbers of other images that are the same as that image.  No matter what you do, the OP says that they want to only delete some of the images, and your code was (and still is) deleting them all.

Comment: Your second example isn't even syntactically correct - it won't run at all

Comment: Well. First, I don't mind much about being syntactically correct. I do mind about providing a functional code for intended use. And if I miss according the OP's feedback, I correct/delete. Unfortunately, you're not the OP. As such, you don't know what is the right thing to do / to ask for. To end the discussion, a clear question has an example output. I don't see any.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you'll get no sympathy from others here for submitting code that you don't even bother to check for syntax errors. That's just having no pride in yourself or your profession. There's no excuse for that. If your code doesn't run, who's to say that the logically important parts are any more correct than the rest of it?  How do you know that your algorithm does what you think it does if you never bother to look at the results?  You may not care if your code has actually been tested, but the OP might.  I never submit code I haven't tried myself unless doing so is not possible.

Comment: This discussion has stoped being on-topic. Please continue it in a chat.